# How to preserve newlines at end of files when pushing to orgs with sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx

Our local style guide and tooling (like [Prettier](https://prettier.io/)) automatically add newlines to end of files. However, when I deploy that file to my organization, either with

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath
```

or deploying `manifest/package.xml` to my org, I see that newlines are not respected:

[image: developer console view of newlines removed]

Additionally, when I retrieve the source via `sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest manifest/package.xml`, the newlines are then removed from my local files, creating large diffs.

I know I could do some hacks locally and update our style guide to not include newlines, but that's not my question. How can I make Salesforce/sfdx respect newlines, or prevent newline removal from happening when pulling? I don't see any relevant options in `force:source:retrieve`

Comment: We avoid the issue by making git our source of truth, doing our code development in IDEA with Illuminated Cloud 2 and not retrieving code from our scratch orgs. We only retrieve non-code metadata such as flows, layouts and lightning flexipages and do this very selectively using IC2's retrieval mechanism.

Comment: @PhilW if you add that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We avoid the issue by making git our source of truth, doing our code development in IDEA with Illuminated Cloud 2 and not retrieving code from our scratch orgs. We only retrieve non-code metadata such as flows, layouts and lightning flexipages and do this very selectively using IC2's retrieval mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-plugin-prettier) is an sfdx plugin which uses Prettier to automatically re-format files as they are retrieved from the org.

A disclaimer from the repository: "THIS IS JUST A SAMPLE PLUGIN, IT IS NOT OFFICIALLY SUPPORTED."

`$ sfdx plugins:install sfdx-plugin-prettier` to install was the only necessary setup for me.