# Empty lines after each line in LWC meta files

Tags: lightning-web-components, metadata, vs-code, xml, formatting

After `sfdx force:source:retrieve -x manifest/package.xml` my meta files (only LWC) have empty empty lines after each line.
Before retrieve:

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>false</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

After retrieve:

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

    <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>

    <isExposed>false</isExposed>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I had XML Red Hat extension for VSCode enabled. But though i disabled it im still getting those newlines after retrieving.
It formats ONLY `*.js-meta.xml` files

Comment: I would expect this is a Windows vs Linux line endings issue. Windows uses CR+LF whereas Linux uses just CR. Take a look at [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274149/how-to-preserve-newlines-at-end-of-files-when-pushing-to-orgs-with-sfdx) for some possible workarounds.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea about this?  It is still happening for me on about half of my LWC meta files upon sfdx force:source:retrieve.